# Juggle Producer and Consumer in Asyncio Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, io, python-asyncio

I have a **producer** and a **consumer** async function. The producer runs first and then three consumers consume the task concurrently. I want to continue this cadence indefinitely.

- What is the best way to stop the **producer** and send a signal to the **consumer** to start running?
- What is the best way to stop the **consumer** and send a signal to the **producer** to start running?

My current setup looks like this:

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def producer(event):
    n = 0
    while True:
        print("Running producer...")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        n += 1
        if n == 2:
            event.set()
            break


async def consumer(event):
    await event.wait()
    print("Running consumer...")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def main():
    event = asyncio.Event()

    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(producer(event))] + [
        asyncio.create_task(consumer(event)) for _ in range(3)
    ]

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


while True:
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("\nSleeping for 1 sec...\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

This produces the following output:

```
Running producer...
Running producer...
Running consumer...
Running consumer...
Running consumer...

Sleeping for 1 sec...

Running producer...
Running producer...
Running consumer...
Running consumer...
Running consumer...
```

The snippet above will run the producer and the two consumers indefinitely. This works as expected:

- The producer and the two consumers run concurrently
- The `while` loop surrounding `asyncio.run` is running the system indefinitely

However, I was wondering if there is a better synchronization technique to achieve this long-running periodicity?

Comment: You could have the producer place values into a queue and have the consumers read them. Also, unrelated, you don’t need to use `create_task` if you’re going to immediately call `gather`.

Comment: Thanks for the `create_task` tip. Yes, I can use a queue to collect value from that. However, my producer fetches message from SQS and it needs to run periodically so that it can collect messages to feed the consumers. Hence, the necessity to run the producer and the consumers continuously.

Comment: The producer can run, fetch messages from SQS, place them in an `asyncio.Queue`, and then the consumers can grab them. If you want the producer to run periodically, you can use `asyncio.sleep`. For the consumers, if there’s nothing in the queue, they can sleep and try again; if something’s there, it can process it.

Comment: @dirn This is an interesting take on the problem. Do you mind sharing an example as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using an event to wake up your consumers is to synchronize the producer and consumers using a queue. The code would look something like

```
import asyncio


async def producer(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        print("Running producer...")
        message = await fetch_message_from_sqs()
        if message:
            await queue.put(message)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def consumer(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        print("Running consumer...")
        if queue.empty():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            continue
        message = await queue.get()
        print(message)
        await acknowledge_message(message)


async def main():
    # You can set a max size if you want to prevent pull too many messages from SQS.
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    tasks = asyncio.gather(producer(queue), *[consumer(queue) for _ in range(3)])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Are the check for `q.empty()` and the sleeps necessary? They seem to introduce latency for no good reason.

Comment: @user4815162342 probably not. `Queue.get` is smart enough. The function to fetch from SQS probably should be too.